# Optimize queries for tables with large text columns (15k - 5000k)

Tags: mysql, web-crawler, large-data

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `html` (
  `html_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `links_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tld` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  ....
  `html` mediumtext  
  PRIMARY KEY (`html_id`,`links_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `links_id_url_index` (`links_id`,`url`(255))
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

- it has > 20 GB of data total (~1 mil rows)
- queries are mostly for statistics and don't require the `html` column
- ex: `SELECT tld, MAX(URL), count(*) FROM html GROUP BY tld`

also the table has to endure many inserts (>500/s) from a multithreaded c++ web-crawler with the `(html_id,links_id)` & `(links_id,url(255))` key checks, and in this configuration it works fine, but by adding other keys I'm afraid it could slow it down.

From all my tests it seams that the large `html` column is the cause of slow queries, what is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the html column to another table. Also, why would you run MAX() on a varchar column?

Comment: it was an example, I coud use MAX on varchar to just get an example url for that tld, of course it would be faster if it could return just the first occurrence.

Comment: I thought of this, but would't this make things a little harder to keep track, and also double the number of queries and unique key checks, also I would need to give an id to the new `html` table and keep track of it , or clone the 3 columns used in key checks (`html_id`,`links_id`,`url`) ?